# How to enable scrollbar for TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

I need to construct a JFace dialog, which consists of a `TreeViewer`.

This is how I have overriden the `createDialogArea(Composite)` method:

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
{
    parentComposite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    parentComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    sc = new ScrolledComposite (parentComposite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    composite = new Composite (sc, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(composite);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ExplorerContentProvider(rootFolderType, shell));
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new ExplorerLabelProvider());
    viewer.setInput(rootFolderComponent);

    sc.setContent(composite);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)); 

    return parentComposite;

}
```

With the above code, this is my Observation:

I have 100 elements in the tree, so I have an outer scrollbar (since I used `ScrolledComposite`). Then if I expand each element I get another scrollbar for the `TreeViewer`.

Can I achieve this with a single scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the ScrolledComposite and it has solved the issue. TreeViewer itself handles the scrollbars dynamically.